# Null ref from inside WebDeploy

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

Just had this error for a previously working auto deployment on TeamCity via MS Web Deploy 3.0.

Seems like a bug. Null reference exceptions should never surface from an API, naked.

> Error: (3/27/2014 5:04:31 PM) An error occurred when the request was
>   processed on the remote computer.  Error: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.
>       at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceEventStreamSerializer.WriteException(Exception
>   e)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData
>   asyncData, Nullable`1 passId)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData
>   asyncData)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData
>   asyncData)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.BeginProcessRequest(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest
>   workerRequest, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)  Error count:
>   1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran the build in TC again. It was a fluke.